# IndexError while iterating through a generator

Tags: python, generator

I am trying to solve a problem for my programming classes. I am given a folder that contains e-mails and special files. Special files always begin with "!". I am supposed to add a method emails() inside the Corpus class. The method should be a generator. This is the example of its use:

```
corpus = Corpus('/path/to/directory/with/emails')
count = 0
# Go through all emails and print the filename and the message body
for fname, body in corpus.emails():
    print(fname)
    print(body)
    print('-------------------------')
    count += 1
print('Finished: ', count, 'files processed.')
```

this is the class and the method I've written:

```
class Corpus:
    def __init__(self, path_to_mails_directory):
        self.path_to_mails_directory = path_to_mails_directory

    def emails(self):
    iterator = 0
    mail_body = None
    mails_folder = os.listdir(self.path_to_mails_directory)
    lenght = len(mails_folder)
    while iterator <= lenght:
        if not mails_folder[iterator].startswith("!"):
            with open(self.path_to_mails_directory+"/"+mails_folder[iterator]) as an_e_mail:
                mail_body = an_e_mail.read()
            yield mails_folder[iterator], mail_body
        iterator += 1
```

and I tried to run the example code this way:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_corpus = Corpus("data/1")
    my_gen = my_corpus.emails()
    count = 0
    for fname, body in my_gen:
        print(fname)
        print(body)
        print("------------------------------")
        count += 1
    print("finished: " + str(count))
```

Python prints quite a bunch of mails (the folder contains about a thousand of files) as expected and then goes:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tvavr/PycharmProjects/spamfilter/corpus.py", line 26, in <module>
    for fname, body in my_gen:
  File "C:/Users/tvavr/PycharmProjects/spamfilter/corpus.py", line 15, in emails
    if not mails_folder[iterator].startswith("!"):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have no clue what the problem is and would appreciate any help. Thx

EDIT: I updated the code a bit based your suggestions.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect your `while 1` loop to exit?

Comment: `os.listdir` returns a list of files (e.g. `["file1.txt", "file2.txt"]` and so on), you treat it as it was a 2 dimensional array. Remove the `[0]` from your line.

Comment: @CristFati - that's true but won't fix the user's exception. `mails_folder[iterator][0]` will be the first letter of the file name, and it's valid to check whether that letter `startswith("!")`. Unnecessarily verbose compared to just checking the file name itself, and not safe if the string could be the empty string (I don't think it can be in `os.listdir`'s result) but it's not the core problem here.

Comment: Your stack trace says `if not mails_folder[iterator][0].startswith("!"):`, but I don't see "if not" anywhere in your code. Are you sure the code producing this error is the code you're showing us?

Comment: True, the problem you identified is most likely the root cause of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this would be as follows:

```
def emails(self):
    mail_body = None
    mails_folder = os.listdir(self.path_to_mails_directory)
    for mail in mails_folder:
        if mail.startswith("!"):
            pass
        else:
            with open(self.path_to_mails_directory+"/"+mail) as an_e_mail:
                mail_body = an_e_mail.read()
            yield mail, mail_body
```

Index based iteration is not considered to be Pythonic. You should prefer "for mail in mails_folder:" syntax.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it fixed the issue.

Comment: Safety; you'd never get an Index error. Readability; python programmers are not used to seeing index based loops. I would also imagine that Python is optimized for 'for x in y:' style of looping.

Comment: Sure, i'm sorry, i'm new to stack over flow